# How to get the response count of SOAP UI test step

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

My requirement is to get the message size and the response count of each test step in my SOAPUI test case and store in a oracle database coulmn.

1st Part :
I am using a groovy script after the test step to get the message size of a SOAP UI test step.
and then i store the value in a object called reponseData 
And that object is stored in an array.

```
def resArray = context.getProperty("RES_DATA_ARRAY")
def resData = context.getProperty("RESPONSE_DATA")
long messageSize = testRunner.results[testRunner.results.size()-1].getMessageExchanges().size.get(0)
responseData.set.xxxxxxx //Some more values set in responseData object
responseData.setMessageSize(messageSize)
resArray.add(responseData)
```

2nd Part : 
Later in the teardown script of the test case I'm iterating through the resArray and getting the message size values of each test step and inserts those data in the db.

I have no issue in the 2nd part of this requirement.
In this way i can get the message size of the test step.

Is there something similar which i can use to get the response count of a particular test step?

Comment: some test steps which i'm using could give multiple responses. What i want is to get a count of those responses :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you're using this script as a `tearDown script` of your `TestCase`, which is executed when the `TestCase` ends.

This script is not counting the size for all requests and responses on your SOAPUI `TestCase`, it's counting only the size of one of your `TestSteps` more exactly for the last one in your `testCase` because you're accessing the last result:

`testRunner.results[testRunner.results.size()-1]`

Anyway if you want to apply your method to the response of a specific `TestStep` you can define a closure inside your `tearDown script` an use it to get a particular response size:

```
// define the closure
def getResponseSizeByTestStepName = { testStepName ->
    // for each result
    def resp = testRunner.results.find { 
        // compare the testStep name an return the object
        // for the desired one
        if(it.testStep.name.equalsIgnoreCase(testStepName)){
            return it
        }
    }
    return resp.size
}

log.info getResponseSizeByTestStepName('Test Request')
```

I think that there is no other way which doesn't iterate over all results list because there is no method to get the specific result for a `testStep` for example by name or other reference.

**UPDATE**

After you change your question, actually I don't understand well your requirement about "response count" since there is one response from `testStep` anyway if you want to access your response to do something with it you can change your script as follows:

```
def resArray = context.getProperty("RES_DATA_ARRAY")
def resData = context.getProperty("RESPONSE_DATA")
def result = testRunner.results[testRunner.results.size()-1]
long messageSize = result.getMessageExchanges().size.get(0)
// get the response...
def response result.testStep.getPropertyValue('response')
log.info response
// do something with the response...

responseData.set.xxxxxxx //Some more values set in responseData object
responseData.setMessageSize(messageSize)werqwerwerwerwerqwer
resArray.add(responseData)
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: The question was not explained well enough. I edited it. 
Could you please check now because it's not the message size of the test case,its the test step. And i can get the message size, its the response count i'm struggling with. :/

Comment: @direndd sorry I don't understand yet the question. What do you means for response count? the number of responses?

Comment: some test steps which i'm using could give multiple responses. What i want is to get a count of those responses :)

Comment: You mean more than 1 XML in the output ?